# Visual Paradigm ERD Questions

Tags: entity-relationship, visual-paradigm

I'm new to both Visual Paradigm and ERD.  I created an entity, but am a bit lost what some of the notation is.  I'm not sure what the large 'N' is, or the number 10 associated with the ID integer (both were autogenerated when creating a column).  Any help would be great, I can't seem to find this in the documentation.

[image]

Comment: It seems as though 'N' represents an item that is nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "N" indicate the column is nullable or not.

The column type (integer or number) is subject to the target database specified for your project (under Tools > DB > Database Configuration). For example, by specify project target DB as Oracle then the columns with integer(10) will automatically change to number(10).

You can mark a column as primary key by simply adding "+" sign in front of the column name while in-line editing the column in ERD.

[image: Adding "+" sign in front of column to mark it as primary key]

You can find the general ERD modeling tips for Visual Paradigm at https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/3563/3564/85375_drawingentit.html